# How to print string in jsf Facelets page?

Tags: jsf

*(intro: I have generated Entity Clases from DB with one tabe lets say Beans, so it generated me Beans.java, BeansFacade.java, BeansController.java and AbstracFacade.java than I added JSF pages from entity classes, and just want to add something to list.xhtml)*

In my BeansFacade.java I have

```
public String simple(){
        return "output";
    }
```

In BeansController.java I hava

```
public String printSimple(){
        return ejbFacade.simple();
    }
```

And than whem I try to print that

```
 <h:outputText value="#{beansController.printSimple}"> </h:outputText>
```

I get an error 
*javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException:*

The class 'fct.entity.EventsController' does not have the property 'printSimple'.

Answer (score 3):

You are not able to call the method in `h:outputText`.
`h:outputText` tries to search the given variable related `getter/setter`

```
private String printSimple;

public String getPrintSimple()
{
    return ejbFacade.simple();;
}

/**
 * @return the simple
 */
public String getSimple()
{
    return simple;
}
```

And than whem you can use the simple variable to get the value.

```
<h:outputText value="#{beansController.printSimple}"> </h:outputText>
```

before that call the `printSimple` method.